# filtering nested (foreign key) queryset in django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a queryset in Django:

```
    models.User:
       id = pk
       username = text

    models.Offer
       id = pk
       user = Fk(User)
       description = text

    my serializer is:

    class UserOfferSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        offers = OfferSerializerAll(many=True, read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('id', 'username', 'offers')
```

I am trying to filter it by a snippet of text appearing in the description text and it is straightforward (to filter the first level object, the User) but then I want to filter the offers of each user and get back the users with the wanted offers. 
I am trying:

```
queryset.filter(offers__description__icontains = sometext)
```

but I get the User with all the offers he has.

Any help, Thank you!!

Comment: What is this kind of code ? I don't understand your queryset. Please edit more clearly your script.

Comment: That's not a queryset. Please show your actual models.

Comment: showing it as json:P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To limit related offers with custom queryset you can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) with `Prefetch` object:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

User.objects.filter(offers__description__icontains=sometext).prefetch_related(Prefetch('offers', queryset=Offer.objects.filter(description__icontains=sometext)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is almost what I want, I tried your solution, it works fine but it duplicates the User object.

Comment: saying that I have only one user with two offers which match the query, it will return a queryset with two User objects and each contains two Offer objects.

Comment: What I want is to get back only one User object with the two matching offers.

Comment: I added the distinct: User.objects.filter(offers__description__icontains=sometext).prefetch_related(Prefetch('offers', queryset=Offer.objects.filter(description__icontains=sometext))).distinct()